Why did early ASCII have ← and ↑ but not ↓ or →?
It is widely known and reported that the 1963 definition of ASCII had ↑ and ← at positions 0x5E and 0x5F.  Soon after these were changed to ^ and _ and so they remain.
The first terminal I ever used was a Teletype model 33:

The shift-N and shift-O did indeed print ↑ and ←, as advertised on the keycaps, and I have been puzzled by the absence of ↓ and → for almost fifty years.
Why were ↑ and ← in ASCII to begin with?  Whose idea was it to put in ↑ and ← but not ↓ or →, and what was those characters' intended use?
Update: The elimination of  ↑ and ←  appears to have been very early, pre-ASCII.  The April 1965 "Proposed Revised American Standard Code for Information Exchange" (Comm. ACM) reports that the ISO 646 committee, working in parallel with the ANSI X3.4 committee, had replaced ↑ and ← with ^ and backtick (not underscore) as early as December 1963.  (See figure 2 on p.212.)  The history here is very convoluted and I would appreciate a clear explanation from someone who understands how the various threads relate. So the main question is still:
How and why ↑ and ← were in the 1963 definition to begin with.

This question is similar to: Why did the C64 have ← and ↑ as dedicated keys?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

I did read that question before I posted. It is clearly different. The answer to the C64 question is “because they were following ASCII”. My question is why was ASCII that way to begin with.

Not for nothing but my answer on that question does include the why "The ← and ↑ symbols were originally included in ASCII-1963 as programming operators", or at least the only "why" I could find evidence of at the time I wrote it.

I don't really see that having an up-arrow really leads to an expectation of a down-arrow.

It's All In The 1963 Proposal
Note that those early versions (i.e., all before 1968) were proposals for the upcoming standard (*1) - not prior standard or preliminary versions. The earliest form only defined codes from x'00' to x'5F'. The intention was for

x'5E' as exponential mark - as in 5x10↑8 - while
x'5F' is described as 'Implies/Replaced By': what one today would call an assignment (*2).

Thus, neither is an arrow in itself, but a dedicated mathematical symbol like '<' and '>'.
This usage is nicely described in section 4 on p.5 and p.6 of the 1963 proposal:

(Images of the pages taken from this fine site)
Changing ↑ to ^ added a diacritical mark (used with BS), using that new  character for exponential notation was still a meaningful read - so good that we still use it: 5x10^8.
A similar thing happened with ←. While exponential is still something used very often, a special assignment was only picked up by APL. By dropping this very specific character the position was free to be used for another 'mark' - here underscore which allowed (again with BS - or CR) underlining of text.

*1 - And a lengthy process it was: more than 5 years until a final standard was agreed on. All in a world moving extremely fast. Even faster than micros evolved in the early 1980s. That's why many manufacturers implemented intermediate proposals in their new products... or had to use other solutions. Which is what IBM did. The /360 was originally intended to use all-out ASCII, but it not being finished, they came up with EBCDIC as an intermediate solution. Early /360 hardware was even switchable to use ASCII instead (for BCD/printable conversion), as they tried until the very last moment to keep that door open. Once EBCDIC was out in the wild (1965), no customer wanted to change all their data, so EBCDIC it was. The machine bit to switch for ASCII was in turn dropped in the mid 1970s.
*2 - While most languages settled for using = or := as assignment operator, IBM's APL insisted on an left pointing arrow ... among many many others :) Although APL was first published only in 1965, its notation was internally used as shorthand to describe machine operations as early as 1962. Being a main proponent for ASCII, IBM Engineers using that might have had a word here.
The inclusion is a bit funny as the paper explicitly states in Appendix A5 on Page 7 that "it is not practicable to include all of the ALGOL graphics (which number 120)".

But yes, it makes sense to have a unique assignment operator. One only needs to remember all the errors C programmers made with '=' vs. '=='. Could have been all prevented if only the 1963 version had persisted.
(Here's BTW a nice page about the history of assignment operators)
*3 - In the 1963 proposal x'7F' was strictly a paper tape/transmission character defined as an idle non-character.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.
